# Error in cordova(ionic) android/php application

Tags: php, android, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm making a android application with ionic/cordova in client side and php in the server side, but every time I test it I get this error

**----------------------------------------------------------------------------**

**Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://restaurent.eb2a.com/app/test.php?callback=angular.callbacks._0".**
**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <**

**failure**

**undefined**

**404**

**----**

**----------------------------------------------------------------------------**

This is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <button ng-click="clicked($event)">Click me</button>
  </div>

  <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
      $scope.clicked = function($event) {
        var url = "http://restaurent.eb2a.com/app/test.php?callback=JSON_CALLBACK";
        $http.jsonp(url).success(function(data) {
          //console.log("success");
          if (data['reponse'] == 'true') {
            console.log("success");
            console.log(data);
            console.log("----");
          }
        }).error(function(data, status) {
          console.log("failure");
          console.log(data);
          console.log(status);
          console.log("----");
        });
      };
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

And this is my test.php

```
<?php

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Request-With');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo $_GET['callback'] ."({'reponse': 'true'})";
?>
```

Note: whene I test this same code with browser, it work fine.

Comment: Are you sure that you're calling `restaurant.php` and not `test.php`?

Comment: not restaurants, imean test, sorry

Comment: Correct your question text :)

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need a config in your Request:
[angular http-jsonp](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#jsonp)

Like this:

```
headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
```